# Populate date based on combobox selection

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have two items in ComboBox1, one is Cardio Only and second is Gym Only.
I want to auto populate Renew Date in TextBox8 based on Combobox1 selection.

e.g.
If I select "CARDIO ONLY" then Next Renew date should be 90days + currentdate or 3 months + current date in TextBox8.
If I select "GYM ONLY" then Next Renew date should be 30days + currentdate or 1 month + currentdate in TextBox8.

(in days)
90 + 22/01/2022 = 22/04/2022
30 + 22/01/2022 = 21/02/2022

(in months)
3 + 22/01/2022 = 22/04/2022
1 + 22/01/2022 = 21/02/2022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

   Dim mth As Long
   Select Case Me.ComboBox1.Value
       Case "GYM ONLY"
           mth = 1
       Case "CARDIO ONLY"
           mth = 3
   End Select
   If mth > 0 Then
       Me.TextBox8 = Format(DateAdd("m", mth, Date), "dd/mm/yyyy")
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This vba code works like charm :) I am so happy because after 3 days of frustration is over. 
THANKYOU SO MUCH!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this to add 3 months to the current date:

```vb
DateAdd("m", 3, Date)
```

this to add 90 days to the current date

```vb
DateAdd("d", 90, Date)
```

Note that adding days and adding months does not always yield the same result, depending on the number of days in the months.

E.g. `DateAdd("m", 1, #2002/1/30#)` yields `2002/02/28`.

But `DateAdd("d", 30, #2002/1/30#)` yields `2002/03/01`.

See also: [DateAdd function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateadd-function?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1013094);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)